# why is there black spots flashing on my pictures on lumix dmc tz80?

Tags: digital, camera-settings, camera

i bought a second hand lumix DMC TZ80, and there’s like black flashing things popping up on my pictures i took on it, like the picture i put here, the black things appear in the spots where it’s very bright spots and when i used flash. How do i get rid of it?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> You can set overexposed areas (areas that are too bright and where
> there are no shades of grey) to flash on the screen when the [Auto
> Review] function is activated or during playback. This does not affect
> recorded pictures.

[Page 57 of the manual](https://www.panasonic.com/content/dam/Panasonic/MEA/pdf-download/cameras-camcorders/DMC-TZ80.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The flashing black areas are not actually part of the pictures. They're a warning shown on the camera's rear screen. As you have surmised, they are warning you of areas in the image that have been exposed so brightly that no details are recorded for those areas.

Most cameras have a menu item that allows the user to turn this warning on or off. I'm sure your camera's [*User Manual*](https://www.manua.ls/panasonic/lumix-dmc-tz80/manual) tells you how to do this.